# Different tests for different variables of the same data type in gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have a dataframe and hope to present p value of baseline table using Gtsummary, with different tests for different variables of the same data type.
(eg. Use fisher exact test for some categorical variables and chi square tests for others.)

For example,

```
 # create example data
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.frame(a = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 b = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 c = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 d = sample(c("Low", "Medium", "High"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 e = sample(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 f = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 g = rnorm(100),
                 h = rnorm(100))`
```

I hope to that b c can be tested by fisher.test and d e f can be tested by chisq.test. (Divided by a )

I tried:

```
mydata %>%  
tbl_summary(     
by = a,                                            
statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{median} ({p25}-{p75}",        
                 all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)")
)   %>% add_p(all_continuous() ~ 't.test',
             all_categorical(-c('b','c')) ~ "chisq.test",
             c('b', 'c') ~ "fisher.test", pvalue_fun = function(x) style_number(x, digits =                 3))`
```

This does not work. I guess there is some thing wrong with the `all categorical(-c(‘b’, ‘c’))`, but is there a way to rapidly removing certain variables from `“all categorical()”`?

A more advanced question is, how can I let the function detect which is the best test to use?  I found that add_p will not automatically use fisher’s exact test when the data do not meet the standard of chi square.

Thank you all for the kind help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specifically call the `test` argument in `add_p()`. Also I am not sure about this syntax `all_categorical(-c('b','c'))` so I changed it below.

```
    mydata %>%  
  tbl_summary(     
    by = a,                                            
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{median} ({p25}-{p75}",        
                     all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)")
  )   %>% add_p(test = list(c("g","h") ~ 't.test',
                            c("d", "e", "f") ~ "chisq.test",
                            c('b', 'c') ~ "fisher.test", pvalue_fun = function(x) style_number(x, digits =3))
  )
```

Sorry when I used the `-c("b","c")` for the chi square test it also included the continuous variables in that group. Above I explicitly mentioned each variable to include for each test. If you need it to be more dynamic I can amend the code.

edit:
First you can identify all categorical variables and save it as `colchar` and then in a second step remove the variables from that list that are your by variable and two variables you want to use a fisher test for. Then pass `colchar_chisq` as your list of variables to the `add_p()` test argument

```
colchar <- colnames(mydata)[sapply(mydata, is.character)]

colchar_chisq <- setdiff(colchar, c("a","b","c"))

mydata %>%  
  tbl_summary(     
    by = a,                                            
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{median} ({p25}-{p75}",        
                     all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)")
  )   %>% add_p(test = list(all_continuous() ~ 't.test',
                            all_of(colchar_chisq) ~ "chisq.test",
                            c('b', 'c') ~ "fisher.test", pvalue_fun = function(x) style_number(x, digits =3))
  )
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the reply!!  I tried the code but it seems that "list(all_continuous() ~ 't.test'" did not work and continuous variables (g, h) are still tested by chi square test (and the foot note of the table did not include "t.test").

Comment: Thank you Mike! This is a very good way to finish the task. But if I have many variables and cannot list them one by one. Do you know whether there is a way to make selection function such as "all_categorical()" work. (like remove b and c from all_categorical)? Thank you so much!!

Comment: made code more dynamic take a look

Comment: no problem if this is the correct solution for you consider up voting and accepting as the correct answer